# I am currently attempting to create a matrix from a text file in R where the first column is actually the row names

Tags: r, matrix, row

I have a text file of over 14 million lines that I am attempting to convert to a matrix in order to create a heat map from its contents. The format of a condensed version of the text file is as follows:

```
A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 ...
AA 1  3  5  7 ...
AB 3  4  1  9 ...
BA 9  8  3  3 ...
BB 4  2  1  0 ...
```

I want it to read in as a matrix where the rownames are AA,AB,etc. I am currently using

```
mymatrix<-fread("C:\\filelocation.txt")
```

this returns a matrix that reads out

```
   A0 A1 A2 A3 ...
1: AA  1  3  5  ...
```

etc.

How do I make it a matrix that actually looks like the text file?

Thanks!

Comment: According to a [comment made by the package author (and maintainer)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448732/reading-csv-with-row-names-by-fread#comment-21887535), it doesn't look like he supports row names.

Comment: Using `fread`, if you pass `data.table = FALSE` and `drop = 'A0'` arguments, you can read in `A0` separately (using `select = 'A0'`) and set the row names manually. You're still getting a data.frame out, though, not a matrix. There are functions for reading actual matrices that may better suit your needs; maybe `tseries::read.matrix` or `e1071::read.matrix.csr`.